# Make index available on the run not after completion

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, cleo

I am creating lucene index and on the top of that creating cleo index.

The problem is that the data on which this index is going to be created is very large, it may be 1 billion.

I want to make the index available as soon as the indexes are generating. Not after completion.

Let's say I am indexing 1 billion records and I have generated an index of 1 million records. So that one million index is available for search. Why wait for so long?

Right now i am able to create cleo index only after complete indexing of lucene index.
And cleo search result is only available after complete cleo indexing.

Let say i have 100 records & indexed 10 records & 90 records are pending & i need to search on that 10 data .Currently i am able to search only after indexing of 100 records.
I want to make data available for search as soon as it is been index
Means that 10 record should be available in search not wait for remaining 90 records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either commit often, or use [near-realtime search](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/NearRealtimeSearch). The later can be done using [DirectoryReader.open(IndexWriter writer, boolean applyAllDeletes)](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/DirectoryReader.html#open(org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter,%20boolean)) to open a reader which you can use for searching documents not yet committed.